# How to: Add custom extension method to Expression class. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, expression

I have an custom extension method like following

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> AnyCollection<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
{
    ICollection<EDMX.ApplicantEducation> abc = (ICollection<EDMX.ApplicantEducation>) source;
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Is it possible to include it to Expression class so I can use it like this

```
var temp=Expression.Call(predicate, typeof(Models.ApplicantEducationVM).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                   .AnyCollection(...);
```

Is it possible?How?

Comment: @Christos I followed this its giving compile time error `cannot convert MethodInfo to Expression` when I try to pass my method to Expression.MakeMemberAccess

Comment: I re-opened your question, since that didn't help.